# Coverage report says zero coverage on android with gradle

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I've been unable to get code coverage to work on any of my android projects.

To simplify things I created a new project (selected empty activity).
Added a new utility class to the the project in src/main/java.

I then created a unit test for it in src/androidTest/java.

Updated the gradle file to enable coverage.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.michaelkrussel.coverageapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    jacoco {
        version "0.7.1.201405082137"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
             testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

I ran the tests then using ./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport.  The unit test shows that the test I created passed, but the coverage report reports zero coverage.

I assume I'm either missing something in the gradle file or not running the correct gradle task, but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: try add In defaultConfig { testApplicationId "your.package.test"}

Comment: @anderson_acs Tried to add it, and I still have an empty coverage.ec file and the report says 0 coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this configuration in my project and work fine!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.acs.app"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testApplicationId "br.com.acs.app.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1') {
        exclude group: 'junit' 
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you're include junit 4.  Are you running standard Java unit tests or are you running android instrumented tests?

Comment: yeah! I'm running instrumented tests.

Comment: Well coping our gradle file still didn't fix my problem, but did tell me that it wasn't a gradle configuration problem.  I decided to try running the tests on a different device and everything started working.  The device that didn't work was a Nexus S4 mini running Android 4.4.2.  I also tried an emulator using Android 4.4.2, and it worked.  So the problems seems to be my specific device (not sure what).  Thanks for showing me a working example.  I also learned about the testing-support-lib which looks cool.

Comment: Yes Michael Krussel is right, I had the same problem I did extensive experiment with Samsung Galaxy S4 (4.4.2), It was giving me an empty coverage.ec but when I tried same config with LG-Nexus 5 (5.1.1) it worked fine. Also where are you trying to find *.exec or *.ec files ? look at your project-directory/build/outputs/code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec